# nested array not formatted as expected

Tags: php, arrays

Hello i have a problem with the logic to have a multidimentional array for each while loops that i had. I do not know why is it not working.

i wanted to have like this as concept

```
data >
      ser_id > 14
               org_name > "org a"
      ser_id > 15
               org_name > "org b"
```

but the output is like this

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [ser_id0] => 14
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Gannon University
                )

            [ser_id1] => 15
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Lions Club
                )

            [ser_id2] => 16
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Rotatory Club
                )

        )

)
```

Can you help me with the logic. Here is the code i worked on with rows loop fetched from db.

```
        $rs = $this->crud->fetchResultSet("services");

        $rows = array();
        $i=0;
        while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()){

            //$rows = arra
            $ser_id = $row["ser_id"];
            $rows["data"][$i] = $ser_id;
            $orgrs = $this->crud->fetchSingleResultSet("organizations","ser_id",$row['ser_id']);

            $j=0;
            while($innrow = $orgrs->fetch_assoc()){
                $rows["data"][$i][$j] = $innrow["org_name"];
                $j++;
            }
            $i++;

        }
```

Comment: Array keys CANNOT be identical,

Comment: thats why i have ser_id0,serid1

Comment: use multidimensional array like this =>>


$a[$i]['ser_id']=$row["ser_id"];

$a[$i]['org_name']=$innrow["org_name"];

Comment: Could you clarify your example then? Because I'm not sure what kind of structure you wan then, it's hard to see what is key and what is value.

Comment: i think my logic should have been like what @mohade said

Comment: group of information in each array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use multidimensional array like this =>>

```
 $a[$i]['ser_id']=$row["ser_id"]; 
$a[$i]['org_name']=$innrow["org_name"]
```

and restore data like this

```
$max=count($a[$i]);
for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
echo 'ser_id =>'.$a[$i]['ser_id'];
echo 'org_name =>'.$a[$i]['org_name'];
}
```